# CheckBoxes in Xcode (iPhone Programming) question

Tags: xcode

Ok the problem is that i need to do like a summary of a list of things to do, with a checkbox at the right... The state 0 of the checkbox is a png with an empty checkbox, and the state 1 is when the user touch in it, and it should display a png with a marked checkbox, everything must reset at midnight..
How can i do that?